# Equivalent of _phptemplate_variables()

Tags: 6

There is a function in Drupal 5 (`_phptemplate_variables()`) that has been deprecated in Drupal 6.
Is there a similar function in Drupal 6?

Comment: It seems to me that your question title doesn't match with what you explain in the body... Could you please clarify?

Comment: For those of you looking for Equivalent function in D6 and above, look at GoogleTorp's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, i'm not totally sure what you mean, but according to the title of the post, you want a redirect function ?

something like the drupal_goto(); function?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6

Answer (score 4):

`_phptemplate_variables` in D5 have been changed into multiple functions.

The Drupal preprocess functions have changed from Drupal 5 -> Drupal 6, to make them hook based. So instead of having a single function that could be invoked for different hooks, Drupal 6 uses the naming system similar to how hooks is used in modules.

This is described in detail on Drupal.org: [Converting 5.x themes to 6.x](http://drupal.org/node/132442#theme-templates)

Answer (score 2):

`_phptemplate_variables()` is not a function that has been deprecated. It is simply a private function that is not used anymore.

Drupal 5 PHPTemplate engine looked for a function with that name to alter the variables used in a template.

```
function _phptemplate_callback($hook, $variables = array(), $suggestions = array()) {
  global $theme_engine;

  $variables = array_merge($variables, _phptemplate_default_variables($hook, $variables));

  // Allow specified variables to be overridden
  $variables_function = '_'. $theme_engine .'_variables';
  if (function_exists($variables_function)) {
    $variables = array_merge($variables, call_user_func($variables_function, $hook, $variables));
    // …
  }
  // … 
}
```

What the code for Drupal 6 needs to do is to implement `MODULE_preprocess(&$variables)`, or `MODULE_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)` (where `HOOK` is `page`, `node`, `comment`, or any of the values defined from a theme or module).

Answer (score 0):

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-' . str_replace('_', '-', $variables['node']->type);
  }
  return $variables;
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for Equivalent of _phptemplate_variables()